# When in a conditional does this assignment occur?

Tags: java, xojo

I am porting some Java code to Xojo which doesn't have the same language constructs as Java does.

I have a bug in the port and I think I've narrowed it down to this bit of Java code:

```java
int maxIndex = 0;
int n = vertices.length; // vertices is an array
double max = dot(vertices[0]), candidateMax; // I'm assuming `candidateMax` is being initialised to 0 here.

if (max < (candidateMax = vector.dot(vertices[1]))) {
  // Search to the right
  do {
    max = candidateMax;
      maxIndex++;
  } while ((maxIndex + 1) < n && max < (candidateMax = vector.dot(vertices[maxIndex + 1])));

} else if ( max < (candidateMax = vector.dot(vertices[n - 1])) ) {
  maxIndex = n;
  // Search to the left
  do {
    max = candidateMax;
     maxIndex--;
  } while (maxIndex > 0 && max <= (candidateMax = vector.dot(vertices[maxIndex - 1])));
}
return maxIndex;
```

I've ported it to this code (Xojo - more verbose than the code above):

```
Var maxIndex As Integer = 0
Var n As Integer = Vertices.Count
Var max As Double = vector.Dot(Vertices(0))
Var candidateMax As Double

candidateMax = vector.Dot(Vertices(1))
If max < candidateMax Then
  // Search to the right.
  Do
    max = candidateMax
    maxIndex = maxIndex + 1

    // Exit?
    If maxIndex + 1 >= n Then
      Exit
    Else
      candidateMax = vector.Dot(Vertices(maxIndex + 1))
      If max > candidateMax Then Exit
    End If
  Loop
Else
  candidateMax = vector.Dot(Vertices(n - 1))
  If max < candidateMax Then
    maxIndex = n

    // Search to the left.
    Do
      max = candidateMax
      maxIndex = maxIndex - 1

      // Exit?
      If maxIndex <= 0 Then
        Exit
      Else
        candidateMax = vector.Dot(Vertices(maxIndex - 1))
        If max > candidateMax Then Exit
      End If
    Loop
  End If
End If

Return maxIndex
```

I'm assuming the `while` loop conditional:

```java
if (max < (candidateMax = vector.dot(this.vertices[1]))) {
  // Search to the right
  do {
    max = candidateMax;
      maxIndex++;
  } while ((maxIndex + 1) < n && max < (candidateMax = vector.dot(vertices[maxIndex + 1])));
```

translates as: "Do the contents of the loop at least once. After each iteration of the loop, check to see if `maxIndex + 1` is less than `n`. If it's not then exit the loop. If `maxIndex + 1` is greater than `n` then assign the result of the `vector.dot` method to `candidateMax` and check to see if `max` is less than `candidateMax`. If it is then keep iterating".

Is this correct? I think I'm misinterpreting the order that the `while` conditional is being evaluated.

Comment: *"I'm assuming `candidateMax` is being initialised to 0 here."* You're assuming wrong. `candidateMax` is unassigned. It will however be definitely-assigned in the next line of code.

Comment: *"Is this correct?"* Yes, except the opposite of `max < candidateMax` is `max >= candidateMax` in the first loop. Looks like a copy/paste error, or you simply missing that first loop uses `max <`, while second loop uses `max <= `.

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas! You're right, I overlooked the difference between `max <` in the first loop and `max <=` in the second loop. Tired eyes :)

Comment: A while loop is only executed if the condition is true. If the condition is false, it will never execute.

Comment: @NomadMaker True for a `while (...) { ... }` loop, but not true for a `do { ... } while (...)` loop, which executes the body once before checking the condition.

Comment: Correct. I didn't read it closely enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you got the loop exit condition wrong.

Original:

```
while (maxIndex > 0 && max <= (candidateMax = vector.dot(vertices[maxIndex - 1])))
```

would mean in Xojo, roughly:

```
  ...
  if maxIndex > 0 then candidateMax = vector.Dot(Vertices(maxIndex - 1))
while (maxIndex > 0) and (max <= candidateMax)
```

In general, you can translate Java/C's `do ... while (b)` into Xojo's `do ... loop until not (b)`.

This would mean, in your case:

```
  ...
  if maxIndex > 0 then candidateMax = vector.Dot(Vertices(maxIndex - 1))
loop until not ( (maxIndex > 0) and (max <= candidateMax) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about translating to `do...lop until not`. Very helpful. The only slight issue with this particular loop condition is that a variable (`candidateMax`) is being assigned to within the condition, something that isn't (at least I don't think it is) possible in Xojo.

Comment: I want to up-vote for the `do ... loop until not (...)`, but at the same time I want to down-vote for the rest of it. The Java code is `do { ... } while (maxIndex > 0 && max <= candidateMax)`, which is the same as `while (true) { ...; if (maxIndex <= 0 || max > candidateMax) { break; } }`, and that is exactly what the code in the question has for the Xojo version. Before that you say *"But you turned it into"*, as-if that is wrong, but it is the correct code. Your *"would mean in Xojo"* code is wrong, and your `loop until not ( (maxIndex > 0) or (max <= candidateMax) )` is wrong.